# How to get bearer tokens in microk8s?

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

I want to log in to the microk8s dashboard, but I need a bearer token. How can I find the bearer token for user `admin` in microk8s Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

In microk8s, bearer tokens are listed in file `/snap/microk8s/current/known_token.csv`. [Each line is of the format](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/):

```
bearer_token,user,uid,"group1,group2,group3"
```

In the following example file the bearer token for user `admin` is `rICHredacted4YWK`:

```
RPY4redactedS65i,system:kube-proxy,kube-proxy
rICHredacted4YWK,admin,admin,"system:masters"
tzgVredactedW4YW,system:node:ip-172-31-14-2,kubelet-0,"system:nodes"
```